# Show that a system of intersecting $D4$-$D6$ branes is supersymmetric

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, branes

The paper [*"Supersymmetric Gauge Theories, Intersecting Branes and Free Fermions"*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.4446) asserts (first paragraph, page 12,section 2.4) that a system of $N$ $D4$-branes intersecting with $k$ $D6$ branes along two flat directions (say on a 2-torus) is supersymmetric.  The paper suggests that this can be shown by mapping the system by a series of $T$-dualities into a $D0$-$D8$ or $D1$-$D9$ system.

Question: **How can I explicitly obtain the duality transformation?**